# I need to add a new column to split out my current data into 4 new row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This is my current code which will produce one row per employee, I then need to split that employee into 4 rows with a new column as "Quarter" and then 1,2,3,4 as the values for those new rows please.

I will then need to join the the current AMD table on this quarter as well once created, which I think should be easy enough

```
Select 

Concat(Employees.Firstname, " ",Employees.Lastname) as FullName,
Employees.JobRole,
Employees.Location,
COUNT(Distinct AMD.Id) as ForumRenewals
```

Comment: Does this AMD table already have four rows per employee?

Answer (score 1):

You can expand each row of a table into 4 rows with additional column using **UNNEST()**

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE sample AS
SELECT 'John' AS FullName, 'Manager' AS JobRole, 'NY' AS Location, 10 AS ForumRenewals;

SELECT * FROM sample, UNNEST([1, 2, 3, 4]) Quarter;
```

output:

[image]